# Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded error

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know that the above question has been asked many times. But those did not solve my problem.
Here is the problem statement :

I am trying to download zip file using 'ajax', I have read many posts that **FILE DOWNLOAD IS NOT POSSIBLE USING AJAX**
So I tried to hack it, I don't know my approach is correct or not, I just tried it.

So what am I doing is .. I am sending the byte from My controller. to my ajax call, and trying to make it downloadable.

here is my ajax call

```js
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'myURL',
            data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            crossDomain: true,
            accept: "application/zip",
            success: function (data) {
            // i get the data here from my controller 
            var sampleBytes = base64ToArrayBuffer(data);
                saveByteArray([sampleBytes], 'black1x1.gif');

                function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
                    console.log("base64ToArrayBuffer called");
                    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
                    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
                    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
                    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
                        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
                        bytes[i] = ascii;
                    }
                    return bytes;
                }

                var saveByteArray = (function () {
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.style = "display: none";
                    return function (data, name) {
                        var blob = new Blob(data, { type: "octet/stream" }),
                            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        a.href = url;
                        a.download = name;
                        a.click();
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    };
                }());
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

But when I convert the data to base64, I get the above error.
please, don't mind, I might be doing some foolish thing, I just tried,
can any one help me to solve the problem.

Comment: A .zip file isn't base64, so the error is correct, you're trying to parse binary as base64

Comment: What should I do then? any suggestion

Comment: You are trying to cheat the system. Even if you succeed this, there's no guarantee that future browser version won't block you. This seems to me as a worthless effort.